# where can I get on chain data?

Tags: full-node, raw-data

I'm trying to make some On chain data analysis, but almost all providers are not free
so the question is if I set up a full bitcoin node will be able to extract real time data from it?
seems like stupid question but I just want to make sure if I'm right here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have a lot of data from a full node. Transaction history, fees paid, hashrate (indirectly), address use and history, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded the bitcoin core and got my hands on the data :)